# How to apply activeadmin authentication to external page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, activeadmin

I am using activeadmin gem which is going fine, now i want to add its authentication to some external pages or as MVC you say to some action. don't mix it with the actions which can be added from admin/users.rd files. these are those action that reside out side of activeadmin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use a Devise (which Active Admin uses for authentication) for a page in the same app but not an actual Active Admin page I did the following:

in my routes.rb I added a new route:

```
devise_scope :admin_user do
  resources :products
end
```

then in my products_controller.rb i added a before_filter to restrict access:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!
```

Hope that helps!